# TFS Source control shortcuts

Tags: tfs

My team has a super long folder structure that I have to click through everytime I decide to use TFS source control explorer.

How can I avoid this?

Is there a way to create a folder shortcut or for TFS explorer to remember my last place that I was in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is in the tfs power tools (an extension you can find on the visual studio gallery). This installs a file explorer addin that allows you to do source control actions in any file  explorer window, so you can use regular folder shortcuts with it.

Answer (score 3):

Favorite Documents extension (https://vlasovstudio.com/favorite-documents/) is great. You can create shortcuts to TFS Source Control folders, and to a solution folders and files. It adds menu item: Favorites to your Main Menu. Check it out.

Pawel